# Unrecognized selector sent to instance on segue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, segue, unrecognized-selector

I perform a segue in this code and it has been verified that the correct identifier is 'showContacts'

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showContacts"]) {
    SwipeTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.albumObj = album;
}
```

On the last line of this block, I get this error message:

```
2014-07-22 10:00:18.333 LayoutTest[710:60b] -[UITableViewController setAlbumObj:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x965d810
2014-07-22 10:00:18.336 LayoutTest[710:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setAlbumObj:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x965d810'
```

This is where I declare albumObj in my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SWTableViewCell.h"
#import "Album.h"

@interface SwipeTableViewController : UITableViewController <SWTableViewCellDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) Album* albumObj;

@end
```

And this is where it is synthesized in my SwipeTableViewController.m file:

```
@implementation SwipeTableViewController

@synthesize albumObj;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have done segues with the same object in the exact same way and it has worked fine. Why am I getting this issue with this segue? I'm thinking that maybe I should be declaring the albumObj in the table app delegate like this:

```
@interface SwipeTableAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Album* albumObj;

@end
```

but then it doesn't look like I can access albumObj in SwipeTableViewController.m like I need to.

Comment: destViewController isn't what you think it is.  Just because the pointer has a type does not mean the object is of that type.  (This is not Java.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `segue.destinationViewController` is giving you a `UITableViewController`. That's why it's saying `setAlbumObj` is unrecognized. That method doesn't exist on `UITableViewController`. Make sure your destination is a `SwipeTableViewController` in your storyboard.

Comment: Doesn't it create the setalbumObj method when I synthesize it in SwipeTableViewController.m?

Comment: The problem is that you have a `SwipeTableViewController` _reference_ that is _pointing_ to a `UITableViewController`. You need to tell your storyboard to create a `SwipeTableViewController` **instead** of a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: @halleyw Yes, it does. The problem, however, is that it's not `SwipeTableViewController` that gets instantiated from your story board.

Answer (score 2):

One reason why this would happen is a discrepancy between your story board and your code: your segue assumes that the destination of the `:@"showContacts"` segue is `SwipeTableViewController`, while in the story board the class of the destination is set to the default `UITableViewController`.

Open the story board, select the destination view controller of your segue, set its type to `UITableViewController`, recompile, and run. This should fix this problem.

Comment: This was mostly my problem. The issue was that the destination view controller class needed to be set to SwipeTableViewController. Thank you